# AutoHotkey.dll: "new CoCOMServer()" causes Exception

Tags: c#, dll, autohotkey, stack-overflow

I successfully downloaded the Autohotkey_H 1.1 package from

http://www.autohotkey.net/~HotKeyIt/AutoHotkey/files/AutoHotkey-txt.html

I then successfully registered the Win32w version (in the "Win32w" folder) of the AutoHotkey.dll with regsvr32.

Then I started Visual Studio 2012, started a new Project and referenced the DLL in the project successfully.

The project has only the following code:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      CoCOMServer ahkThread = new CoCOMServer();
    }
  }
```

upon running the code, the following error occurs:

http://imageshack.us/f/822/pn3y.png
(StackOverflowException in mscorlib.dll)

I am using Windows 7 64 bit. The error occurs on 2 different machines with the SAME setup.

Has anyone successfully used the DLL with Visual Studio and give me some hints on what you did differently?

EDIT:

Also, this does NOT work in VB:

```
Sub atest()
Dim AhkCom As Object
Set AhkCom = CreateObject("AutoHotkey.Script")
AhkCom.ahktextdll("MsgBox Hello World!" & Chr(13) & "ExitApp")
End Sub
```

And neiter does this:

```
dynamic ahk = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("AutoHotkey.Script.UNICODE"));
ahk.ahktextdll("msgbox hello world");
```

And this **DOES** work in Autohotkey itsself:

```
AhkCom := ComObjCreate("AutoHotkey.Script")
AhkCom.ahktextdll("MsgBox Hello World!`nExitApp")
While AhkCom.ahkReady()
  Sleep, 100
MsgBox Exiting now
```

Last one proves that the DLL is, in fact, working.

In fact it shows very clearly that the problem is Visual Studio specific. Tried 2010 aswell by now.

If someone can tell me what I am doing wrong I would be eternally grateful. Do I need to specify more than those 2-4 lines of code? Do something with Interop? I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the example on their Website (in VB)

```
Sub atest()
Dim AhkCom As Object
Set AhkCom = CreateObject("AutoHotkey.Script")
AhkCom.ahktextdll("MsgBox Hello World!" & Chr(13) & "ExitApp")
End Sub
```

This illustrate how you connect to the COM server. CreateObject() is the key of course

Comment: The C# equivalent would be Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("AutoHotkey.Script"));
same error!

Comment: I am suggesting you use VB as is the test the COM server, if the VB.Net example does not work, you won't be able to connect from C# either. C# 4.0 supports the equivalent dynamic binding

Comment: Well, that means the COM server is not correctly installed for some reason. I would reinstall / register first. If still completely broken, try an ActiveX inspection tool to see if what is registered matches the docs.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your error, you need to register the correct dll, it is located in the
Multi-threaded Dll MD folder, once you do this the visual basic code will work
I faced this same problem and was relieved to figure things out so I am happy to
help you